# Recursive Teradata Query

Tags: sql, recursion, teradata, recursive-query

I'm trying to query the below table into a consolidated and sorted list, such as:

Beginning list:

```
GROUP_ID    MY_RANK EMP_NAME
1   1   Dan
1   2   Bob
1   4   Chris
1   3   Steve
1   5   Cal
2   1   Britt
2   2   Babs
2   3   Beth
3   1   Vlad
3   3   Eric
3   2   Mike
```

Query Result:

```
1   Dan, Bob, Steve, Chris, Cal
2   Britt, Babs, Beth
3   Vlad, Mike, Eric
```

It needs to use a recursive query because the list is much longer. Also, I have to sort by my_rank to get them in sequential order. Thanks in advance. I've tried about 10 examples found on different forums, but I'm stuck. Also, don't worry about truncating the any trailing/leading commas.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TEST (GROUP_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, MY_RANK INTEGER NOT NULL, EMP_NAME VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (1, 1, 'Dan');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (1, 2, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (1, 4, 'Chris');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (1, 3, 'Steve');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (1, 5, 'Cal');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (2, 1, 'Britt');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (2, 2, 'Babs');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (2, 3, 'Beth');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (3, 1, 'Vlad');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (3, 3, 'Eric');
INSERT INTO MY_TEST VALUES (3, 2, 'Mike');
```

Answer (score 3):

What's your Teradata release? Are XML-Services installed?

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.FunctionsV
WHERE FunctionName = 'XMLAGG';
```

If this function exists you can avoid recursion (which is not very efficient anyway):

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, 
   TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM
             CAST(XMLAGG(EMP_NAME || ',' ORDER BY MY_RANK) AS VARCHAR(10000)))
FROM MY_TEST
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Another fine answer. I found this while looking for recursion alternatives. I ended up having to use `TRANSLATE_CHK` as well, since just Character Set wasn't preventing "untranslatable" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE employees(Group_ID , Employees, MY_RANK) AS
(
    --Recursive Seed
    SELECT
        GROUP_ID,
        --Cast as a big fat varchar so it can hold all of the employees in a list.
        CAST(EMP_NAME as VARCHAR(5000)),            
        --We need to include MY_RANK so we can choose the next highest rank in the recursive term below.
        MY_RANK 
    FROM
        MY_TEST
    WHERE
        --filter for only my_rank = 1 because that's where we want to start
        MY_RANK = 1

    UNION ALL

    --Recursive Term
    SELECT
        employees.GROUP_ID,
        employees.EMP_NAME || ', ' || MY_TEST.EMP_NAME,
        MY_TEST.MY_RANK
    FROM
        employees
        INNER JOIN MY_TEST ON

            --Joining on Group_id and Rank+1
            employees.GROUP_ID = MY_TEST.GROUP_ID AND
            employees.MY_RANK + 1 = MY_TEST.MY_RANK

)

SELECT GROUP_ID, Employees FROM employees;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm getting an error, "SELECT Failed 3500: Invalid SQL statement, expected DELETE INSERT PROCEDURE SELECT OR UPDATE". I'm using teradata sql assistant the database is through Access. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your RDBMS is Access? If so this def won't work. You will need some VBA and it won't be pretty.

Comment: I transitioned the database outside of access. I was getting an error "employees.EMP_NAME" does not exist. Should that be "employees.Employees"?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. It should be `employees.employees`.