# How to concatenate rows together until a condition is met in Teradata 13

Tags: concatenation, teradata, reset, rank

I have the following table:

```html
ID_CLT  STEPS             INNER RANK
61081   ROUND_SIG_1               1
61081   AR_OK                     2
61081   ABS_FT                    3
61081   ROUND_SIG_2               1
61081   TECH_DISPATCH             2
61081   AR_OK                     3
61081   RET_FT                    4
61081   RET                       5
61081   CLOSED                    1
```

I want to concatenate the steps together until the INNER RANK is reset to 1,in other words, I want the following output:

```html
ID_CLT  STEPS                                           INNER RANK
61081   ROUND_SIG_1 AR_OK ABS_FT                             1
61081   ROUND_SIG_2   TECH_DISPATCH AR_OK REFT_FT RET        1
61081   CLOSED                                               1
```

Concerning the input table, the simplified version of the query I use is:

```
SELECT alpha.ID_CLT , 
             alpha.STEPS,
             rank() over (partition by alpha.ID_CLT
            order by alpha.RNK
           RESET WHEN (alpha.STEPS LIKE 'ROUND%' OR  alpha.STEPS LIKE 'CLOSED')) as SEQQ FROM (  SELECT  ID_CLT, STEPS, RNK) alpha
```

Where the RNK column orders the different steps in time for a given ID_CLT

Is there any idea how I can proceed to obtain this result? I have tried many tricks with rank(), row_number() and RESET WITH syntax but it didn't work...

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Comment: What's the query to get this result? You need an ORDER BY to determine those groups.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply... On which value should I ORDER BY my rows? It is true that the STEPS occur sequentially in time, but this is not enough to create the subgroups I want to concatenate... I was thinking about using the variations in the INNER RANK, something like this: when the current rank is lower than the previous one, stop the concatenation and start a new one...

Comment: RESET WHEN can't produce the groups you want, but the logic used by RESET is similar to: `SUM(CASE WHEN  (alpha.STEPS LIKE 'ROUND%' OR  alpha.STEPS LIKE 'CLOSED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CLT 
            ORDER BY RNK
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS grp`. You might be able to do that as part of the `alpha` Select. Now you got your `grp`, the concat can be done using `XMLAGG`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200980/recursive-teradata-query

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the logic... although I cannot use XMLAGG (since it needs a version over 15), I can still make it work with a REPLACE RECURSIVE VIEW.. Regards

Comment: Afaik since 14.10 XML is part of the basic installation, before there was an add-on package. For recursion you should check if the recursion operates on the result set of the previous query (good) or re-calculates the data for each level (bad), in any case it will use lots of spool. If the maximum number of rows per group is know (and small) multiple concats using `MAX(CASE WHEN rnk = 1 THEN STEPS ELSE '' END)` might be more efficient